# Unable to open codename one file in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, codenameone

Hello I am new to codename one and I tried following their installation guide to use it with Eclipse. I've already downloaded codename one from the eclipse marketplace but I can't seem to open a file with it. Heres what happened in the tutorial:

file>new>other>codename one

However, there is no codename one option when I press other. I've tried reinstalling it but it hasn't worked.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I've fixed the problem. I uninstalled again and redownloaded it by pressing

help>install new software

instead of the eclipse marketplace. I then pasted in this link into 'work with':

http://www.codenameone.com/files/eclipse/site.xml

I think the issue was that I was downloading it from the eclipse marketplace and that seems buggy for me. :D